# My wordpress website doesn't work on MS Edge / IE.

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Recently I've been working on a website for my client. I want to make clear that I'm not a proffessional webdeveloper, I'm a designer with some basic coding skills. I've created some simillar wordpress pages before, and never encountered that problem. Even though I'm using the same theme (Stockhoml by Select Themes) on all of my websites.

The address is: http://odlotowebusy.pl

Everything seems to be fine when the page loads, but when I try to scroll down it all fades to white (only in Edge/IE). I have no idea what couses this problem. Meybe somone here will be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried disabling all the plugins you are using and enabling them one at a time to see if any of them affect the site?